# How to edit the "import sys" in PyCharms' python console?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Even though I'm trying to run a program from my `diff_document_viewer` folder my Python console is importing from `pyggi`.

I'm not sure why this is happening as I was not messing around in the settings before this happened. I had just changed the name from the file Frame to frame in the terminal, and it caused this problem after I closed and reopened it.

I have reinitialized the python-console but this is not working. Not sure how to go in and edit so python-console imports from the correct file.

```
/home/john/Git/diff_document_viewer/venv/bin/python /snap/pycharm-community/123/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=37311

import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))

sys.path.extend(['/home/john/Git/pyggi'])

PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
```

Should be showing:

```
sys.path.extend(['/home/john/Git/pyggi'], ['home/john/Git/diff_document_viewer'])
```

it might also be:

```
sys.path.extend(['/home/john/Git/pyggi', 'home/john/Git/diff_document_viewer'])
```

but point is it's not including `diff_document_viewer`. Any advice on how to change this in PyCharm is appreciated.